# How to access instance variable in block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, block, instance-variables

I want to access an instance variable in the block, but always receive EXC_BAC_ACCESS within block.I don't use ARC in my project.

```
.h file

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    int age; // an instance variable
}



.m file

typedef void(^MyBlock) (void);

MyBlock bb;

@interface ViewController ()

- (void)foo;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __block ViewController *aa = self;

    bb = ^{
        NSLog(@"%d", aa->age);// EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
        // NSLog(@"%d", age); // I also tried this code, didn't work
    };

    Block_copy(bb);

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200);
    [btn setTitle:@"Tap Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(foo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)foo{
    bb();
}

@end
```

I'm not familiar with blocks programming, what's the problem in my code ?

Comment: please post your declaration of age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the block which was allocated on the stack which is no longer in scope. You need to assign `bb` to the copied block. `bb` should aslo be moved to an instance variable of the class.

```
//Do not forget to Block_release and nil bb on viewDidUnload
bb = Block_copy(bb);
```

Comment: If that is your complete class then you will also need to Block_release `bb` in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Thanks. It's just a demo. I know the problem. I find a strange syntax: if define bb like this, ` @property(nonatomic, copy) BB bb; ` then I can use `self.bb();` to call it in `foo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should define proper accessor methods for your `age` ivar:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
  int age; // an instance variable
}
@property (nonatomic) int age;
...
```

in your .m file:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize age;
...
```

and the use it like this:

```
    NSLog(@"%d", aa.age);// EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
```

if you allocate properly ViewController so that its instance is not deallocated before the block is executed, this will fix it.

Comment: A property is not necessary if `age` is intended to be private.